# Python Regex - Positions and Values of Matches of Unicode Text

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have to match multiple occurrences of tokens in a document and get the value and the position of the matched token.

For non-Unicode text I'm using this regex `r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(word) + r"\b(?!\w)"` with `finditer` and it works.

For Unicode text I must use a word-boundary like solution like `u"(\s|^)%s(\s|$)"  % word`. This will work in most of cases, but not when I have two consecutive words like in "तुम मुझे दोस्त कहते कहते हो".

This is the code to reproduce this issue.

```
import re
import json

# a input document of sentences
document="These are oranges and apples and and pears, but not pinapples\nThese are oranges and apples and pears, but not pinapples"


# uncomment to test UNICODE
document="तुम मुझे दोस्त कहते कहते हो"

sentences=[] # sentences
seen = {} # map if a token has been see already!

# split into sentences
lines=document.splitlines()

for index,line in enumerate(lines):

  print("Line:%d %s" % (index,line))

  # split token that are words
  # LP: (for Simon ;P we do not care of punct at all!
  rgx = re.compile("([\w][\w']*\w)")
  tokens=rgx.findall(line)

  # uncomment to test UNICODE
  tokens=["तुम","मुझे","दोस्त","कहते","कहते","हो"]

  print("Tokens:",tokens)

  sentence={} # a sentence
  items=[] # word tokens

  # for each token word
  for index_word,word in enumerate(tokens):

    # uncomment to test UNICODE
    my_regex = u"(\s|^)%s(\s|$)"  % word
    #my_regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(word) + r"\b(?!\w)"
    r = re.compile(my_regex, flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)

    item = {}
    # for each matched token in sentence
    for m in r.finditer(document):

      token=m.group()
      characterOffsetBegin=m.start()
      characterOffsetEnd=characterOffsetBegin+len(m.group()) - 1 # LP: star from 0

      print ("word:%s characterOffsetBegin:%d characterOffsetEnd:%d" % (token, characterOffsetBegin, characterOffsetEnd) )

      found=-1
      if word in seen:
        found=seen[word]

      if characterOffsetBegin > found:
        # store last word has been seen
        seen[word] = characterOffsetBegin
        item['index']=index_word+1 #// word index starts from 1
        item['word']=token
        item['characterOffsetBegin'] = characterOffsetBegin;
        item['characterOffsetEnd'] = characterOffsetEnd;
        items.append(item)
        break

  sentence['text']=line
  sentence['tokens']=items
  sentences.append(sentence)

print(json.dumps(sentences, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

print("------ testing ------")
text=''
for sentence in sentences:
  for token in sentence['tokens']:
    # LP: we get the token from a slice in original text
    text = text + document[token['characterOffsetBegin']:token['characterOffsetEnd']+1] + " "
  text = text + '\n'
print(text)
```

Specifically for the token `कहते` I will get the same match, instead of the next token.

```
word: कहते  characterOffsetBegin:20 characterOffsetEnd:25
word: कहते  characterOffsetBegin:20 characterOffsetEnd:25
```

Comment: Note that your non-Unicode regex is a bit off as it won't work if the `word` starts with a non-word char. You most probably want to use `r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(word))`. Or,  `r"(?<!\w){}(?!\w)".format(re.escape(word))`

Comment: And your issue with the other regex should be probably fixed with lookarounds - `r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(word))`, check [this demo](https://ideone.com/qUyo2E).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, for the non-Unicode yours regex is better. For the Unicode using `my_regex = r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(word))` it seems it works as well! If you post a answer I will be glad to accept it!

Comment: Ok, let me post it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-Unicode text, you may use a better regex like

```
my_regex = r"(?<!\w){}(?!\w)".format(re.escape(word))
```

Yours won't work if the `word` starts with a non-word char. The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the current location and the `(?!\w)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

The second problem with the Unicode text regex is that the second group consumes whitespace after a word, and thus it is not available for the consequent match. It is convenient to use lookarounds here:

```
my_regex = r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(word))
```

See this [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/qUyo2E).

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location and the `(?!\S)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.